# SharePoint Designer 2013 64 Bit - Freezing on Load

Tags: sharepoint-designer, cache, windows-8

I have a question and when I search, I can't seem to find the answer.  Anytime I run SharePoint Designer, the application loads normally but when I attempt to load any site that are in the Recent List, it freezes.  However, if it is a new site, it loads just fine.  I am thinking there might be a cache issue?  Does anyone know how to remove the cache for SharePoint Designer 2013?

Thanks!
Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

- Make sure SPD is closed.
- Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\SharePoint Designer\Recent Web List` in Regedit. Remove `Recent sites` history .
- Open My Computer  > Click the address bar > Paste in: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache`. Delete everything within this location.
- Click the address bar  > Paste in: `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache`. Delete everything in this location
- Disable the `Cache site data across SharePoint Designer sessions` option in SPD-Options
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing using PowerShell.

Just enter the below code in a PowerShell ISE opened using "Run as Administrator" option.

```
 if(Test-Path $Env:USERPROFILE"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Web Server
 Extensions\Cache")

 {

 Remove-Item $Env:USERPROFILE"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Web Server
 Extensions\Cache" -force -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
}

 if(test-path $Env:USERPROFILE"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache")

 {

 Remove-Item $Env:USERPROFILE"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache"
 -force -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

 }

Write-host "The designer cache is cleared"
```